# how to change the FormatCurrency()?

Tags: asp.net

I am using this line :

```
FormatCurrency(DBReader("Price").ToString, 2, True)
```

to format my Currency 
and I have two websites, the first one is English and the second is Arabic.

In the English website the price will be in $ Currency because the the localization setting is set as "en-US".

In the Arabic website the price will be in ل.ل Currency because the the localization setting is set as "ar-LB".

The question is how to format this code:

```
FormatCurrency(DBReader("Price").ToString, 2, True)
```

to make the currency in the $ only in both websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString), that use the overloaded toString function coupled with a format specifier and locale.

Comment: String.Format("{0:F2}", DBReader("Price"))

Answer (score 0):

In your `FormatCurrency` method make use of `NeutralCulture` or en-US culture

Comment: I cange it to :

FormatCurrency(DBReader("Price").ToString("C", _
                  Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")), 2, True)


and I had this Error:

Too many arguments to 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Chars(index As Integer) As Char!!


can you please show me how to modify the code to make it work Please

Comment: what are you trying to do in your `FormatCurrency` method?

Comment: String.Format("{0:F2}", DBReader("Price"))